# why class name not found when i directly call it laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5, instance, classname

I have to similar classes Laminat and Linoleum

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Parsing\Samara; class Laminat extends BaseSupply {
public $manufacture = 'Без производителя';
public $class = 'null';
public $depth = 'null';
public $collection = 'Без коллекции'; }
```

Linoleum :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Parsing\Samara; class Linoleum extends BaseSupply {
public $manufacture = 'Без производителя';
public $collection = 'Без коллекции';
public $width = 'null'; }
```

and i trying to use it like

```
 $path = "App\Http\Controllers\Parsing\Samara\Linoleum";
 $item = new $path();
 dd($item);
```

if i create instance of laminat it responses with dd

[firstPic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8X0n.png)

if i create instance of linoleum it responses with dd

[secondPic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jaV3.png)

What am i making wrong with this?

Comment: Check the filename `Linoleum.php` and the directory, inside `App\Http\Controllers\Parsing\Samara\`

Comment: I got everything right files - Linoleum.php and Laminat.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that theese classes was not in autoload file. So i ran theese comands

`composer dump-autoload
 php artisan optimize`

and classes was added to autoload file and everything works correctly.

Comment: you dont need to run optimize while in development. if you dont have that optimized file the autoloader will use psr4 autoloading which does not require a composer dump to pick up new files. when you optimize it creates a classmap which would require a composer dump to pick up any new files.